# What boards have integrated USB charging?

Tags: power, usb, adafruit, charging

I've been building wearables, using the adafruit trinket, which I love, its small size is easy to tuck away. But I hate having to unplug the battery to charge it every time. I wired in a SPDT switch, and a small USB charger, but it's kind of a cockamamie solution.

I've seen some devices with a battery adapter, and integrated USB charging, 
but they are larger, and harder to tuck away.

I don't need more than 4 IO ports, I'm just looking for a tiny microcontroller platform with integrated USB charging. I just saw the mkr1000 today, which looks decent, but is still larger than I would like. If you know of a product that meets this description, please let me know.

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2124 maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Feather](https://www.adafruit.com/feather) mainboards are fairly small and have integrated LiPo/Li-ion charging. They're not as small at the Trinket but if you don't need the space on the proto boards then you can examine the design files to see what can be cut away.

Comment: Im looking into that, but Im a newb when it comes to eagle cad

Comment: You can safely cut away the prototype area of the Feather 32U4. Though you'd also cut away the SPI, I2C, and UART pins. So unless your project isn't using any of those, this is not an option. (PS you could still get to SDA and SCL by soldering a wire to the vias)